# Should I use "make" or "makes" in the following statement?

Tags: grammatical-number

Should I use make or makes in the following statement:

> Please explain why your experience and qualifications makes you the best candidate for this position

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9053/should-i-use-the-singular-or-plural-verb-in-mathematical-formulae-two-and-two-m

Answer (score 8):

"Make" should be used here, but the reason is not simply because there is a multiple subject. The rule for subject-verb agreement when there is a multiple subject is this:

> If the multiple subjects are joined by *and*, then the verb is plural.
>   If the multiple subjects are joined by *or/nor* then the verb is singular.

Examples:

> The orange, banana, and the jar always sit on the shelf when it rains.
>   In this scenario, either Job, Barney, or Rachel runs to Mrs. Norris and gives her a piece of fish.

Thus, in your case, "make" is used because your multiple subject is joined by "and".

Comment: One edge case here is when your multiple subjects that are joined by 'or' are themselves plural, in which case the plural verb is still used: `Either the Johnsons or the Andersons visit Old Mrs. Hendricks every week.`

Comment: @Thursagen Well, this means that the rule doesn't change. Because when you are using "or", you are rather referring to a single entity with your verb and thus there is only one subject.

Just my thoughts...

Comment: If the compound subjects notionally comprise a composite whole, singular agreement is often preferred: 'Fish and chips is certainly not _my_ favourte meal.' 'Health and safety is of paramount importance.'

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'make' because the opening phrase contains a *list* of things (experience and qualifications).

> Please explain why [list of things] make you the best candidate...

As opposed to:

> Please explain why [one thing] makes you the best candidate...